# How to avoid linebreak at `http:` in url

Tags: beamer, line-breaking, urls

I have a long url that gets wrapped at `http:` in my layout (using beamer).

This is the latex-code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{url}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Weiterführende Informationen}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item \url{https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/}
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

And this is the result:

[image: Wrong output]

I just want it to break at any of the `/` of the *path* but explicitly *not* after `http://` (i.e. also not after the `/` of the protocol)

Comment: May you try `\usepackage{url}` in your preambel? I know that this works at least for citations.

Comment: @SeRe have you read my question? The issue is not about the `\url` command not working. Its about the line-breakage inside that command.

Comment: Oh sorry, I was to fast :D

So I tried it now and with changing the font size, it is in one line. Is this a possible solution for you?
`\usepackage{url}
% ...
\begin{document}
% ...
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Weiterführende Informationen}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item \small\url{https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/}
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
%...
\end{document}`

Comment: Of course not! The question was about how to *avoid linebreaks*.

Comment: Reducing font size is one way to avoid line breaks. However, you can enter a  `\mbox{}` surrounding your `\url`command. But then it will break befor the URL and you get your item above the URL. I solved it like this now:

`\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{url}
% ...
\begin{document}
% ...
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Weiterführende Informationen}
  
    \mbox{\ding{226} \url{https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/}}
  
\end{frame}
%...
\end{document}`

Comment: I don't need hackish workaround, I need a solution which was already posted as an answer. `\mbox` won't work as well btw. because it'll make the url not break at all which is not what I want (thats why I wrote that I want the url to break at any `/` of the path)

Answer (score 4):

You could --locally or generally -- add the colon to the nobreak list:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Weiterführende Informationen}
  \begin{itemize}\appto\UrlNoBreaks{\do\:}%
    \item \url{https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/}
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I don't know if this is really the "right" solution but it enables me to explicitly control the non-breakage (or even the breakage with `\UrlBreaks`) in urls, which Is why I accepted this.

Comment: Could you explain why you `usepackage`d `etoolbox`? I've tried it without that and it still works?

Comment: When I remove etoolbox in my example I get an error that \appto is not defined.

Comment: Ah ok. I guess it is included by the beamer class then.

Comment: I'm using the beamer class in my example and it doesn't load etoolbox.