# How to fix long URL line-breaks with biblatex? - raggedright

Tags: biblatex

I would like long URLs in Bibliography to be ragged-right (left aligned) and start on a new line if longer than one line. There should be no way there is `https:` alone or after text at the end of line and the URL is continuing on the next line.

I have tried this solution, but it doesn't work: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/15655/106367

Ragged right not working:
[image: Bad URL linkebreaks in bibliography]

Bibliography setup

```
%% The following section sets up the bibliography.
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  style=numeric,
  citestyle=numeric-comp,
  sorting=none,
  sortlocale=auto,
  urldate=iso8601,   %% US date formatting
  date=iso8601,
]{biblatex}

\setlength{\bibitemsep}{\baselineskip} %% Add empty space between bibliography entries
\usepackage{url} %% Add package to handle URL
```

Print Bibliography

```
\begingroup
\tolerance=300
\emergencystretch=1em
\raggedright
\sloppy
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc] %% Print the bibliography.
\endgroup
```

Comment: Try http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/308304/how-to-avoid-linebreak-at-http-in-url/308308#308308. Untested as you didn't provide a complete example.

Answer (score 2):

If you want urls to be split at any uppercase or lowercase letter, try this (from Heiko Oberdiek) in your preamble:

```
\setcounter{biburllcpenalty}{7000}
\setcounter{biburlucpenalty}{8000}
```